# Output file with a specific format in C

Tags: c, file

I’m working on a big project, organised in a certain number of file + the main. One of them contains two functions for the handling of files. One, given a file already opened in writing mode, has the following prototype:

```
int save_to_file (char** mat, unsigned n, unsigned m, FILE* f);
```

Where mat is a pointer to a matrix, that will be written on the file, n is the matrix’s number of rows and m the number of columns. f is the file where to write, and as I said, it’s already opened in write mode. Now: I don’t understand how to have the output file of save_to_file() function in a specific format (in my case I’d like to be a .txt file). I thought about using the rename library function but I don’t think it can work in my case. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "only given a pointer to the file"? How do you open the file?

Comment: I don't follow what it is you want to accomplish.  Are you trying to name / rename the file?  Based on a pointer to *what*?

Comment: Show your code and/or attempt. What's the problem?

Comment: It's a simple thing, just think about it. Try to understand how things work, instead of trying always to find a pre-made solution for everything. If every programming problem was solved and there were no particular and often peculiar problems to solve, I would not do this because it would be extremely boring.

Comment: (you know, Javascript node.js npm has `is-even` [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-even))

Comment: You just "*open*" the output file, and write the contents of the imput file in it finally closing the output file, isn't that what you want? That's the reason of my previous comment.

Comment: I edited the question text to be more detailed and specific.  I’m not looking for a pre-made solution, but for a help on understanding. I read a lot, both on the internet and on some books, but I can’t understand how to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is already opened, you just can write data to it. But you can't choose the output file name however, you can choose the output format.

You can use [fprintf()](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.12.html#printf) and you will be able to build a format string to write your data to the file in text form.

If the expected output is binary, then use [fwrite()](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.12.html#fwrite) passing the values with the address of `&`.